# Adding jQuery to HTML issues

Tags: jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="author" content="EJS">
        <title>Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.html').click(function() {
                $('.html').fadeOut('fast');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <center>

                <nav class="navBar">
                    <a class="html" href="index.html">HTML</a> |
                    <a class="css" href="style.css">CSS</a> |
                    <a href="/js/">JavaScript</a> |
                    <a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
                </nav>

                <a href="http://hil.no/"><img id="hilPic" src="hil.png"></a></img>

            </center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my html-sheet. Why doesn't the jQuery work, any suggestions?
I tried putting the jQuery inside another file and then referencing to it, but it still won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where's the reference to the `jQuery` library? Isn't anywhere in your code.

Comment: you have not added Jquery library,..

Comment: your click event is causing the link to fire.

Comment: Also, learn how to use the browser console to spot `Javascript` errors. F12 is your friend.

Comment: Add jQuery library first `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `href="index.html"` on your link, so whenever you click on it the page will redirect to that index.html

Incase you need to do something before you redirect below code should be of help.

```
$( ".html" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // do your thing here.
});
```

But first you might want to include jquery in your html above the script tag

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's correct, but without the library it won't solve the problem anyway.

Comment: Pointless if jQuery is not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Include jquery libarary

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

and your code be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.html').click(function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           $(this).fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the Jquery in your `<head>` section like this.

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/<your desired version>/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Without loading the jQuery library it won't work. If you want to reference jquery from any other `js` file, make sure you include the lib in that js file.